# Send email to form submitters and admin in HTML format using webform module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, html-email

I am using the web-form module in drupal7 and I have to configure email using web form for administrator as well as the users who submit the form.  I can easily configure email for administrator using email setting but can not configure for the user who submit the form because initially I do not have email address of the users who submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it via your module like below,

Write webform submission hook and send your html formatted mail to the email id

```
// webform submission hook
function MODULENAME_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
    global $user,$language;
    $to = $user->mail;
    $params = array(
                    'body' => "<p> Your html content</p>",
                    'subject' => "You mail subject",
                );
    drupal_mail("MODULEANME", "mail-test", $to, $language, $params);
}
```

then write your own mail hook with html as content type,

```
// mail hook
function MODULENAME_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'mail-test':
            $message['subject'] = t($params['subject']);
            $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
            $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
            break;
    }
}
```